# UIView overlapping with tab bar elements iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I made a view for a switch view. Now I already had tabbed menu buttons in it. The problem is the subview for the switch view seems to be overlapping with the tab bar icons at the bottom. Please help.

[image: iphone x screenshot]

Comment: you should add your code so we can help you better!

Answer (score 2):

i think thats because your tabBar is set to translucent. set it to non-translucent from storyboard or programatically.

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a constraint that sets the vertical space between your subview and your tabbar.

Also, check that your layout respects the iPhone X Safe Area (https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/), from your image it seems that your elements overlap the safe area at the bottom.